# press a key to start function

Tags: c++, keyboard, keyboard-events

I am receiving some data, which I want to receive continuously, from my port and printing on my screen. At the same time, I am writing these in a text file. I want to be able to press a key on my keyboard to start the writing to a text file process. So if I don't press it, it will keep getting the data and just displaying it on the screen but won't write in a text file.

I tried,

```
char x;
cin>>x;
if(x=='0')
 { 
printtoText(buffer);
  }
```

ofcourse that did not work. How could I do that? I searched around the web but came up with nothing. Any help would be great.
Thanks

Comment: What platform do you want to target (you'll need some platform-specific code).

Comment: It's possible that printtoText is where your program is wrong. Can you show the code for that?

Comment: @JerryCoffin just C++

Comment: @JamilSeaidoun updating the question right now.

Comment: @JamilSeaidoun when I take the if statement off the program writes it to a text file just fine. but I want to be able to press a key to start the writing process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact if you want to do this in one thread you can. It won't be elegant but should work.
You can start receiving data in trunks in a loop and check every trunk of received data if key has been pressed. If it has, then activate `printtoText(buffer)`.

EDIT:
I was thinking about something like that:

```
void readFile () {
  char str[256];

  std::cout << "Enter the name of an existing text file: ";
  std::cin.get (str,256);    // get c-string

  std::ifstream is(str);     // open file

  while (is.good())          // loop while extraction from file is possible
  {
    char c = is.get();       // get character from file
    if (is.good())

      //Here perform checkl if the key has been pressed and if yes take additional                  actions

      std::cout << c;
  }

  is.close();                // close file
}
```

Comment: Yes, please take a look.